# Convert boolean method to asynchronous one

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have method that execute Email sender like this:

```
public void SendIt() 
{
    if (_Error && !_Override) return;

    var html = new StringBuilder();
    html.Append(HTMLHeader());
    html.Append(Body);
    html.Append(HTMLClose());

    IsHTML = true;
    SendAsync = true;
    Body = html.ToString();
    Send();
}
```

I want to change this method to asynchronous method so I do:

```
public async void SendIt() 
{
    await Send();
}
```

But I get

> 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no
>   extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type
>   'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Send method:

```
public bool Send() 
{
    var MailFrom = new MailAddress(_From, _From);
    _Email.From = MailFrom;

    if (_To.IndexOf(';') > -1) 
    {
        string[] tolist = _To.Split(';');
        foreach (string toAddress in tolist) 
            _Email.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddress.Trim()));
    }
    else _Email.To.Add(new MailAddress(_To.Trim()));        

    if (_CC != null && _CC.Length > 5) 
    {
        if (_CC.IndexOf(';') > -1) 
        {
            string[] Cclist = _CC.Split(';');
            foreach (string ccAddress in Cclist) 
                _Email.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddress.Trim()));
        }
        else _Email.CC.Add(new MailAddress(_CC.Trim()));
    }

    if (_BCC != null && _BCC.Length > 5) 
    {
        if (_BCC.IndexOf(';') > -1) 
        {
            string[] Bcclist = _BCC.Split(';');
            foreach (string bccAddress in Bcclist) 
               _Email.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bccAddress.Trim()));
        }
        else _Email.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(_BCC.Trim()));
    }

    _Email.Subject      = _Subject;
    _Email.IsBodyHtml   = _isHTML;
    _Email.Body         = _Body;
    _Email.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    // Smtp Client
    var Connection = new SmtpClient(_Server, _Port) 
    {
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        Timeout = 60000
    };

    if (_UserName.Length > 1 && _Password.Length > 1 && _Domain.Length > 1) 
        Connection.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password, _Domain);
    else if (_UserName.Length > 1 && _Password.Length > 1) 
        Connection.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);

    bool bFlag = true;

    Connection.EnableSsl = _SSL;

    try 
    {
        Connection.Send(_Email);
    } 
    catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex) 
    {
        var msg = new StringBuilder();

        for (int k = 0; k < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; k++) 
        {
            var StatusCode = ex.InnerExceptions[k].StatusCode;

            if (StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable || StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy) 
            {
                ErrMsg = "Failed to deliver message to " + ex.FailedRecipient[k].ToString();

                try 
                {
                    if (_TryAgainOnFailure) 
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(_TryAgainDelayTime);

                        // Send the message
                        string sTemp = "";
                        if (_SendAsync) 
                            Connection.SendAsync(_Email, sTemp);
                        else Connection.Send(_Email);
                    }
                    _ErrMsg = string.Empty;
                } 
                catch (SmtpException sex) 
                {
                    _ErrMsg = sex.Message;
                    _Error = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (SmtpException sex) 
    {
        string dat = sex.Data.ToString();
        _ErrMsg = sex.Message;
        _Error = true;
    }
    return bFlag;
}
```

How can I convert this boolean method to async method?

I try something like:

```
public async bool Send() {
```

But I get:

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task

What should I do to solve this? Regards

Comment: It's possible answers to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await) may address your issue.  The [Microsoft documentation on asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) may also help.

Comment: Your `Send` method is very long and needs to be refactored into smaller methods. By looking at it, it seems you repeat the same code a few times. The repeated parts needs to be their own methods, and you can use parameters to control the differences for the tiny differences between each time you rewrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The return type of an async method must be `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`

Like the error states you have to change the return type to `Task<bool>`. You will then have to change the method itself so it awaits a `Task` or returns a `Task`.

```
public async Task<Boolean> SendAsync() { // renamed your method with suffix Async

    // ... code unchanged
    try {
        await Connection.SendMailAsync(this._Email);
    } 
    // ... code unchanged
}
```

As for your other methods that call this they should also return type `Task` unless they are event driven like a windows form or wpf click event.

See also [SendMailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

You must return `Task<T>` if you use `async` method.

Correct definition for your method is:

```
public async Task<Boolean> Send()
```

Also you need to use `await` keyword inside your method.

You can write Send method using [SendMailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_System_Object_).

Example is here:

```
public async Task Send(string to, string subject, string body)
{
    var message = new MailMessage
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    };
    message.To.Add(to);

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
}
```

More details you can review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408397/asynchronously-sending-emails-in-c).

Also please review details about `async/await` programming [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await).

Comment: "You must return Task<T> if you use async method." That's not correct. See Igor's answer.