# (VB.net/.Net 4.0) Waiting for all SMTP SendAsync()

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sendasync

I have a thread program with VB.net which is generating reports and sending emails in async way after it.

It is executed by batch file.

The problem I am facing is, .bat is closed when not all smtp server sendasync are completed. However, email could be received when I run in web application.

Therefore, no email could be received. How can I waiting for all SMTP SendAsync tasks before process end.

```
Private Sub Process()
 reportGenerating()
 fileZip()
 emailSend()
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub emailSend()
 'looping something and prepare message/attachements
 For xxxxxxx
   AddHandler client.SendCompleted, AddressOf SendMailCompletedCallBack
   client.SendAsync(message, id)
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously sending Emails in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408397/asynchronously-sending-emails-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean by *it is executed by a batch file* ?

Comment: @Aron seems theres no await function in .Net 4.0

Comment: @preciousbetine using bat scripting language in notepad to activate program execution

Comment: .net 4.0 is not supported anymore. Upgrade to .net 4.5.2 at the very minimum.